# How can convert mm/yy as date format?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have Order Date column as like `2009-01-28`

I want to to extract `01/09` as a date because. I will plot a line graph. So date order is important

I applied

```
data['M/Y'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Order Date']).apply(lambda d: d.strftime('%m/%y'))
```

but it returns object data type.

How can I do this step?

Comment: What data type did you expect? Numpy has no special support for strings.

Comment: your output from `strftime` is of datatype string, which will have to go into a Series of datatype object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any string object is seen as `object` for pandas series. You can order by the original date strings, and create another column beside it as a string of extracted `%m/%Y` by using something like this :

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

# Sample dataframe
data = pd.DataFrame(data={"original_date": ["2021-01-30", "2018-05-05"]})

# Your code should do this, replace "original_date" with your column name
data["M/Y"] = data["original_date"].apply(
    lambda x: (
        (
            f"{datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%d').month}/"
            + f"{datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%d').year}"[-2:]
        )
    )
)
data.sort_values(by="original_date", ascending=False, inplace=True)
```

P.S : If you have `datetime` as column type for `original_date`, then it's even easier you just do `lambda x : f"{x.month}/"+f"{x.year}"[-2:]`

Alternatively, if you want to plot using the order of months in a year, I suggest to use `Y/M` for a quick sorting of strings.

Answer (score 0):

use `toolist`  to convert the numpy or pandas values to local pythonic values. Then you can use  `.replace('-','/')`
method to convert '-' to '/' then use string slicing to get the last digits of year like by `year = '2021'[2:]` # 21.

I only answered as i can't comment.